# Как уменьшить объем bacup database?

Tags: windows, windows-7, db2, резервное-копирование, база-данных

Выполнил резервное копирование базы данной на DB2. В базе четыре таблички, в каждой по 4 записи. Почему размер бекапа составляет более 100 mb? и как уменьшить размеры бекапа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оно много всего туда пишет. ЕМНИП у db2 в строке есть параметр `COMPRESS`

не,моя ошибка и привычка. :) ошибка изза параметра WITH LOGS, а у вас логгирование не включено. собственно посмотреть конфигурацию можно командой

```
db2 GET DB CFG FOR mydb
```

установить какойто параметр (в примере будет LOGARCHMETH1) командой

```
db2 UPDATE DB CFG FOR mydb USING LOGARCHMETH1 DISK:/db2backup
```

это установит логгирование на диск в папку в корне диска db2backup надо это вам или нет -- не могу сказать) как на винде это будет выглядеть - не знаю А вообще я полный бекап делал командами

```
db2 FORCE APPLICATION ALL 
db2 TERMINATE 
db2 DEACTIVATE DB mydb 
db2 BACKUP DB mydb TO /db2backup COMPRESS
```

Comment: сделал следующее: ALTER TABLE .... COMPRESS YES
Размер бекапа не изменился.

Comment: ? не совсем понял
причем тут alter table?

db2 BACKUP DATABASE my_db2_base ONLINE TO /database/backup COMPRESS INCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING

Comment: у меня появилось сообщение: SQL2413N  Динамическое копирование не разрешается, поскольку база данных не
допускает восстановление или действует условие отложенного резервного
копирования.
Explanation
Online backup cannot be performed while the database is not logging for forward recovery as forward recovery will be required at restore time. Forward recovery is placed into effect by setting either the database configuration LOGARCHMETH1 or LOGARCHMETH2 and then performing an offline backup of the database. Как изменить конфигурацию?

Comment: не,моя ошибка и привычка. :) ошибка изза параметра WITH LOGS, а у вас логгирование не включено.
собственно посмотреть конфигурацию можно командой 

db2 GET DB CFG FOR mydb

установить какойто параметр (в примере будет LOGARCHMETH1) командой
db2 UPDATE DB CFG FOR mydb USING LOGARCHMETH1 DISK:/db2backup

это установит логгирование на диск в папку в корне диска db2backup
надо это вам или нет -- не могу сказать) как на винде это будет выглядеть - не знаю
А вообще я полный бекап делал командами

db2 FORCE APPLICATION ALL
db2 TERMINATE
db2 DEACTIVATE DB mydb
db2 BACKUP DB mydb TO /db2backup COMPRES